# Buildfire: How to modify the Login and Register page?

Tags: mobile, authentication, buildfire

I'm new to buildfire and this is my first question on Stack Overflow. I want to edit the login and register page with additional field (randomly generated PIN), and use it for the login process. Could anyone help me about this issue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Buildfire appears to be a "build your app with HTML/JS/CSS", so the answer is "with HTML/JS/CSS". We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Thanks to answer, i know that the application on buidfire is built with HTML/JS/CSS, they provide their sdk to make our own plugins to include in the application but i had searched a lot that how can the login and the register pages can be modified in buildfire because they does'nt allow to modify those other than the buidfire developers.

Comment: You can hire BuildFire to code for you its just not part of the monthly subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the login and register pages are not customizable.

Answer (score 1):

@attila226 is correct. They are not customizable (for now). However, you can turn off the baked-in Login and create your own if you really wanted to. I've seen other apps do this.